# How to move from activity 2 to activity 3 in android studio

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I've created three activities. My first MainActivity has two buttons, one that takes you to Activity2 and one that takes you to Activity3. Both of those buttons work, I've managed to code them correctly.

But then on Activity3 there's a button that's supposed to take you also to Activity2, and it's not working. I've tried several things but I can't seem to figure it out. Is it possible to code several buttons that lead to the same activity? If so please help cause I'm new at coding and stuff. Also here's how I've been coding the buttons :

1-after creating the activity, I go to the Java file and create a new class. In that class I write the following code :

```
class className : AppCompatActivity(){
    override fun onCreate (savedInstance : Bundle?){
        super.onCreate(savedInstance)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity2)
    }
}
```

Then I add it to the manifest

2-then I go back to the MainActivity and write this :

```
val anyName = buttonName
anyName.setOnClickListener {
    startActivity(Intent(this, class Name :: class.java))
}
```

Of course android studio takes care of everything and imports everything that's needed but the second I add more than two of those in my MainActivity the whole app crashes.

Please explain this as simply as possible as, again, I'm really new to coding and android studio.

Thank you !

Comment: Have you some errors after compilation? Please, if you can, attach all code from 3 activities.

Comment: Oh, maybe I see your problem.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply it is greatly appreciated !! I did a lot more digging and watched a bunch of YouTube videos and I finally figured it out. My problem was that I was coding the buttons in the wrong activities. For example, button 1 exists on activity 2, not MainActivity but that is where I was putting its code, hence it wasn't working. Again thank you so much for the reply !!

Answer (score 0):

To go back on an activity you can just use finish() on any function, but if you want to take any information with you, you should look for more information about startActivityforResult().

However next time upload the code and not this pseudocode please, it would help a lot!

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply it is greatly appreciated !! I did a lot more digging and watched a bunch of YouTube videos and I finally figured it out. My problem was that I was coding the buttons in the wrong activities. For example, button 1 exists on activity 2, not MainActivity but that is where I was putting its code, hence it wasn't working. Again thank you so much for the reply !! Although now I am facing another problem of getting the user's inputted data. I'll do some digging and if I can't find anything I'll ask here for help.

Answer (score 0):

When you creating a new activity, you need also to add to it the new `XML` file, which will be display UI in the Activity page.

You can do it in two ways:
1. Custom. 
  Create a new ClassName.kt (Java.class in Java) and attach inside `onCreate()` method a `XML` layout, which will displaying all `views` in Activity page.
2. With Android Studio.
  Just right-click in your `package name` folder, where appears your, for example, empty activity when you start new an Android Studio Project. Then select `new`, then in bottom side of drop-downed view select type of new activity what you want. For example, it is `Empty Activity`. So, lets sum above information: right-click at your `package name` folder -> `new` -> `type of activity`.

For what below info? I see in your example code, which you show as code in Activity number 3, what you have in `onCreate()` this line of code `setContentView(R.layout.activity2)`. It is line means, what you add `XML` file into your activity. One `XML` file for activity can be used only for one activity if you want to show, after `click` on button another activity. Rather you will see only one screen because two activities use one layout. So, check your activities
need to be something like this:

1.In ActivityOne.

```
class ActivityOne : Activity() {
override fun onCreate (savedInstance : Bundle?) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstance)
  setContentView(R.layout.activity1)

  }

}
```

1.In ActivityTwo.

```
class ActivityOne : Activity() {
override fun onCreate (savedInstance : Bundle?) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstance)
  setContentView(R.layout.activity2)

  }

}
```

1.In ActivityThree.

```
class ActivityThree : Activity() {
override fun onCreate (savedInstance : Bundle?) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstance)
  setContentView(R.layout.activity3)

  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply it is greatly appreciated !! I did a lot more digging and watched a bunch of YouTube videos and I finally figured it out. My problem was that I was coding the buttons in the wrong activities. For example, button 1 exists on activity 2, not MainActivity but that is where I was putting its code, hence it wasn't working. Again thank you so much for the reply !! I genuinely did not think anyone was going to answer. I'm facing a couple more issues but if I can't figure them out after some research I'll sure ask for help here again !

Answer (score 0):

Make sure if you want to create a `new activity`  First right click `app` then goto `new -> Activity -> Empty Activity` .

finally you can add `onClick` in your `Button` tag , then use `startActivity` method.

```
public void methodName(View view) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this,ActivityName.class));
    }
```

**Example Code:**

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void gotoTwo(View view) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this,Activity2.class));
    }

    public void gotoThree(View view) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this,Activity3.class));
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml :

```
 <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="240dp"
        android:onClick="gotoTwo"
        android:text="Activity2" />
```

Don`t forgot to create a new java you should create a new xml file too